# Search Result - xslt - url

Tags: xslt

I have following in XLST to display URL

```
 <td class="ms-vb" style="width: 257px">   
     <a href="{url}">  
      <xsl:value-of  select="url"/>
     </a>      
  </td>
```

The problem is if an url value has 2 spaces then it removes one of the space from the link thus link is broken. Any fix. I have various way but can't find to fix it for over 5 hours.

Comment: Try replacing spaces to `%20` in XSLT. http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Akhoy for the helpful link. The following code works.

```
     <a> 
      <xsl:variable name="myVar" >
         <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="url" />
           <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="' '" />
           <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'%20'" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:value-of select="$myVar" />
       </a>
```